# Change Nova root directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, apiato

After nova installation in **apiato**
I have changed the provider and dashboard path directory at root directory to specific container and I am waiting to see the login page but I got this error **laravel app/Nova does not exist** because nova package search the root directory
Does anyone know how we can change the path of the nova directory??

Answer (score 0):

if I am understanding you question correctly, I think you will also have to manually register your resources path, because Nova, by default expects your resources to be in the `App/Nova` namespace.

You can register the path by `Nova::resourcesIn(app_path('{new-path-here}/Nova'));`

More docs here: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/#registering-resources